Union of list of dictionaries in KDB
I am trying to join an arbitrarily long list of dictionaries into one dictionary where matching keys will take the union of distinct values and new keys are simply inserted. Is there a way to do that using uj?
dd1:(`a`b`c)!(1 2; 3 4; 5 6);
dd2:(`b`c`d)!(7 8; 9 10; 0 1);
dd3:(`a`f`e)!(3 4; 1 1; 2 2);

(uj)/:(dd1;dd2;dd3) just returns the last dict.

What I want is:
(`a`b`c`d`e`f)!(1 2 3 4; 3 4 7 8; 5 6 9 10; 0 1; 2 2; 1 1)


You could use union as opposed to your original union join attempt:
q)(union'/)(dd1;dd2;dd3)
a| 1 2 3 4
b| 3 4 7 8
c| 5 6 9 10
d| 0 1
f| ,1
e| ,2

This handles the unique values too

One method not using uj
q)(,'/)(dd1;dd2;dd3)
a| 1 2 3 4
b| 3 4 7 8
c| 5 6 9 10
d| 0 1
f| 1 1
e| 2 2

If the order of the keys is important
q)`a`b`c`d`e xcols(,'/)(dd1;dd2;dd3)
a| 1 2 3 4
b| 3 4 7 8
c| 5 6 9 10
d| 0 1
e| 2 2
f| 1 1

To ensure only distinct values are taken
q)distinct each(,'/)(dd1;dd2;dd3)
a| 1 2 3 4
b| 3 4 7 8
c| 5 6 9 10
d| 0 1
f| ,1
e| ,2


How can one ensure that only distinct values are taken in the union? So that if you apply the operation twice it does not duplicate the values

Have edited my answer

q)(,'/)(dd1;dd2;dd3)
a| 1 2 3 4
b| 3 4 7 8
c| 5 6 9 10
d| 0 1
f| 1 1
e| 2 2


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
